# Combinatorics proof involving finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am trying to prove the following identity with little success!:

$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (p-k) = p(p+1)/2$.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: It's an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is

$$(p-0)+(p-1)+\ldots+(p-(p-1))=1+2+\ldots+p=\frac{p(p+1)}2$$

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you reindex by letting $j=p-k,$ so that it becomes $$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(p-k)=\sum_{j=1}^pj,$$ which is hopefully a more familiar sum, whose closed form you already know.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ as $p+1 \choose 2$. The left-hand side of the series $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(p-k)$ reduces to $1+2+3+...+p$ as shown by @DonAntonio.

Therefore the right-hand side of your equation is the number of ways you can choose $2$ objects from $p+1$ objects $i.e$ $p+1 \choose 2$

Now consider the left-hand side. Label the objects as $1, 2, ... , p+1$. If you choose the object labelled as $1$, you have $p$ choices for the larger object. If you choose the object labelled as $2$, you have $p-1$ choices for choosing the larger object and so on. Thus you get $p+p-1+ ... + 1$ as the number of ways of choosing $2$ objects from $p+1$ objects.

Therefore $1+2+...+p =$ ${p+1}\choose{2}$ $=\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ And the combinatorial proof is complete.

Comment: It would be better to say the larger object rather than the second object.

Comment: Yes. But I already labelled them.

Comment: If you choose the object labeled $2$, what prevents you from taking $1$ as your second object?  What you have in mind is that $2$ is your smaller object, which means you have $p - 1$ choices for your larger object.